# $\lim_{t \to 0} \int^{b}_a |f(x)-f(x+t)|dx =0.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f$ is Riemann-Stieljes integrable on any closed interval $[a,b]$. Show that $$\lim_{t \to 0} \int^{b}_a |f(x)-f(x+t)|dx =0.$$If $f$ is continuous, then this is clear. I am unsure about the case when $f$ is not continuous, however.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a easy way without Lebesgue integration. What should be working: show the claim for indicator function of intervals. Thus, it is true for step functions. Then, apply some $L^1$ approximation argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the result to be true for continuous functions. Given a Riemann integrable function $f$ (on an interval $[a-r,b+r]$ for some $r>0$) and $\epsilon>0$ there is a continuous function $h$ such that $\int_{a-r}^{b+r}|f-h|\,dx<\epsilon$.

Since $h$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ (that we may assume $\le r$) such that if $|t|<\delta$ then $\int_a^b|h(x)-h(x+t)|\,dx<\epsilon$.

If $|t|<\delta$, then
$$\begin{multline}
\int_a^b|f(x)-f(x+t)|\,dx\le\\\int_a^b|f(x)-h(x)|\,dx+\int_a^b|h(x)-h(x+t)|\,dx+\int_a^b|f(x+t)-h(x+t)|\,dx\\
\le 3\,\epsilon.
\end{multline}$$